# Passing a variable from Taurus yaml file to Jmeter script to switch JDBC connection

Tags: java, jmeter, yaml, taurus

I currently have a jmeter script which I would like to switch it's jdbc connections in the script, by passing a variable at runtime through the taurus yaml.

The aim is to switch environment by setting the variable in the yaml.

Using the [guide](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/#environment-variable-access) provided by Taurus, I created an environment variable under settings in the yaml file as follows:

> settings:
> env:
> ENV_VARIABLE: randomvariabletest

Then using the variable, I call on that in the Jmeter script as follows

[image]

I want the JDBC request to then call the JDBC connection which I have named as randomvariabletest. I was expecting that the JDBC request would read the value which I passed in.

[image]

This doesn't work as expected as I am getting the following error:

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Variable Name must not be null in GET MAX ORDER ID*

What am I doing wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using wrong function, [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) reads a [JMeter Property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) and if you plan to use JMeter Properties for parameterization you need to follow [this chapter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Properties-and-Variables)

If you plan to continue using environment variables you either need to:

- either use [__env() custom JMeter Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#envsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) like `${__env(ENV_VARIABLE,,)}`
- or go for [__groovy() built-in function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like `${__groovy(System.getenv('ENV_VARIABLE'),)}`

Comment: Perfect, this worked. I just used the custom env Jmeter function, thanks for the solution.

Answer (score -1):

**Variable Name for connection pool** in [JDBC Connection Configuratio](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)n elements must match with the Variable **Name of Pool declared in JDBC Connection Configuration** in [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)

Connections and JDBC Requests are connected using this variable.

[image]